# Characteristic of operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with a linear map $T:\mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}^m$ defined by $T(x) = Ax$ and $1 < p,q < \infty$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, I would like to show that $\|T\| \leq (\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^q)^{1/q}$ when $T$ is seen as a map from $l^n_p$ to $l^m_q$.

I know $\|T\| = \max\{|a_{ij}| \:{:}\: i=1,...,m,\: j=1,...,n\}$ when seen as a map from $l^n_1$ to $l^m_\infty$, but have no idea of $\|T\|$ when seen as a from $l^n_p$ to $l^m_q$. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of the operator $\ell_p\to \ell_q$ is $\|T\|=\sup\{\|Ax\|_q: \|x\|_p\le 1\}$, i.e., the least upper bound of $$\left(\sum_i \left|\sum_j a_{i,j}x_j\right|^q\right)^{1/q} \text{ with }\|x\|_p\le 1. $$
For fixed $i$ and $a^i=(a_{i,1},\ldots,a_{i,n})$ Hölder's inequality gives $$
\left|\sum\limits_j  a_{i,j}x_j\right|\le \|x\|_p\|a^i\|_q \le \|a^i\|_q= \left(\sum_j|a_{i,j}|^q\right)^{1/q}.$$
Plugging this in the definition implies 
$$
\|T\|\le \left(\sum_i\sum_j|a_{i,j}|^q\right)^{1/q}.$$